# Is there any way to skip error while restoring database using mongorestore?

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongorestore

I'm trying to restore mongo database of about 2.6TB using mongorestore tool on Mongodb 6.0. The process fails at 73.1% with error

```
fs.chunks.bson: mongorestore cannot transform type bson.raw to a bson document. invalid key found. remaining bytes=[].
```

I would like to know if there is a way to skip this error or if there is any way to resolve the issue.

I tried to restore with different mongorestore flags obtained from internet and mongodb manual with no success. I even upgraded the mongoDb while trying to resolve this issues.

Comment: By default it should continue on error. Did you try `mongoexport` and `mongoimport`?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I did not use the two as the database takes to long (more than 28 hrs) to backup and needs huge resources (I have limited space). Though I can do that when if it is the only way out.

Comment: You don't have to store the export file, you can use pipe `mongoexport <old database> | mongoimport <new database>` and you can try [numInsertionWorkers](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/#std-option-mongoimport.--numInsertionWorkers)

Comment: Thank you, If I got you right, this happens when exporting and importing in the same server. In my case, I am migrating from one data center to another.

Comment: No, as long as the firewall does not block it, you can do it: `mongoexport --uri="mongodb://user:password@hostname-1:27017?authSource=admin" -d ... -c ... | mongoimport --uri="user://admin:password@hostname-2:27017?authSource=admin" -d ... -c ...` Just a note, pipe also works with `mongodump ... --archive=- | mongorestore ... --archive=-`